# Firebase login with multiple app instances issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have two Firebase app instances, when i login, the first (default) instance is populated with the current user, but the secondary app doesn't.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser;//this returns the currently logged in user
firebase.auth(secondaryFirebaseApp).currentUser;//this returns null
```

This is how i'm initializing the secondary Firebase app:

```
var config = {
        databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    };
secondaryFirebaseApp= firebase.initializeApp(config, "secondaryFirebaseApp");
```

How can i programmaticaly set the auth of the secondary Firebase app instance equal to the default one (i'm using the Firebase UI Web to login)

Comment: Why do you need another instance with the same currentUser?

Comment: @bojeil Because i need to connect to multiple Realtime Databases. Each app instance can connect to one database. (I've distributed the  user's data across multiple databases for better scalability )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when initialising the secondary Firebase instance you can keep it global or find the instance using `firebase.getInstance` function.

Anyhow you can authenticate the user for the secondary database as long as you have the reference to that db.

```
const secondary = firebase.initializeApp(config, 'secondary');
firebase.storage();
await secondary.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
```